# Where to set state of this variable?

Tags: reactjs

In reactJS, if your application architecture is as follows, then where will you set the state of this variable (where in component Lifecycle method).

Architecture : 
Components that render differently are based on whether the client reads a state variable.Your application architecture allows you to render something different on the server and client, intentionally. You can do this through two-pass rendering.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please provide some code in order to understand what you're trying to do and the issue you're facing.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, in class components where do you update the state is that whats the question ?

Answer (score 0):

We generally define/init the state right below the class.

state = { 
newState : true
}

If you have to update the state based on some events, example click event, then you have to write a method, that will be called on onClick event. This method can handle state updates.

This is one common use case. There are many ways to do so. I assume you are new to react. Please elaborate your need.